# Openshift using alternative container image

Tags: php, linux, openshift

I currently have a legacy application built in php 5.4, that I'm trying to migrate to openshift.

It seems however, that php 5.4 is not available as a default container image in openshift 3.5. Here's a part of my buildconfig file.

```
    ...
    source:
    type: Git
    git:
      uri: 'https://xxx.git'
      ref: master
    secrets: null
  strategy:
    type: Source
    sourceStrategy:
      from:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        namespace: openshift
        name: 'php:5.5'
        ...
```

As of now, everything works as expected. However, in the sourceStrategy section, if I change the name to: "name: 'php:5.4'" it fails.

Is there any possible way to get a php 5.4 environment?

There seems to be a php 5.4 cartridge at this url: 
https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/origin-community-cartridges/tree/master/openshift-origin-cartridge-php-5.4

How would I integrate it into my openshift environment?

I'm currently running openshift container platform 3.5 on a test machine.

Thank You.

Comment: Cartridges are for older OpenShift V2, not V3 which you are using.

Comment: The only PHP versions support in OpenShift V3 with bundled S2I builders are 5.5, 5.6 and 7.0. https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-php-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Graham the Software Collections Library do not provide a container with PHP 5.4, however there is nothing to stop you creating your own image and deploying that to your OpenShift environment.

Create an image which installs PHP 5.4, example Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum install -y php-common php-cli ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/Packages/php-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64.rpm

CMD ["php", "-v"]
```

Run the following commands to build the image and push it to Dockerhub

`docker build -t docker.io/your-username/php:5.4 .
docker push docker.io/your-username/php:5.4`

You can then use this image to create an ImageStream or reference the image on Docker hub directly in your DeploymentConfig under `containers:["image"]`

Comment: The only issue being that doing it that way will not be S2I enabled and you will need to build up your own image which also includes your files to be hosted.

Comment: Sure, but if he **needs** a 5.4 environment it is either that or create his own S2I image right? This is probably a simpler approach to get started.

Comment: So according to what Graham is saying, with this solution I would not be able to use git to get the source files automatically as I was doing previously? Would I need to add apache in the container as well?

Comment: No what Graham is saying is correct. To do what you are requesting you would need to create your own s2i base image and reference that image stream tag. Should be doable, follow other images here https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-php-container

Comment: Thanks to all who contributed. At the end, we figured it was simpler to simply update the app to work with php 5.5. Hopefully newer versions of openshift will not force us to constantly update an app we no longer wish to maintain.